# An upper bound for number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if the complement of a graph $G$ is disconnected, then we have the following inequality:
$$ |\text{number of edges of}~ G| \leq\Delta(G)^2$$

Such that $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree in the main graph G.

My problem with this question is that I do not know how we can use the disconnectivity fact, Is there any similar problems that gives the lower or upper bound on edges when a graph or its complement is disconnected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use two claims to prove this:

> 1. $\frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}\leq\Delta(G)$
> 2. $E(G)\leq \frac{\vert V(G)\vert }{2}\cdot\Delta(G)$

Using that, we get:
$$\vert E(G)\vert \leq \frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}\cdot\Delta(G)\leq \Delta(G)^2$$

Which is what we wanted to prove.

**Proof of 1:**

If $\bar G$ (the complement of $G$) is disconnected, it has more than one connected component, (so at least two).
Therefore, one of those connected components size is at most $\frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}$.
Denote it by $A$.

Now, let $v$ be some vertex in $G$.
$v$ is adjacent (in $G$) to every vertex $u\notin A$.
Therefore $$\deg_G(v)\vert V(G)\vert-\vert A\vert\geq \frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}$$
and since $\Delta(G)\geq \deg_G(v)$, we get $\frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}\leq\Delta(G)$

**Proof of 2:**

$$2\vert E(G)\vert = \sum_{v\in V(G)} \deg(v)\leq\sum_{v\in V(G)} \Delta(G)=\vert V(G)\vert\cdot\Delta(G)\implies \\ 
\vert E(G)\vert\leq \frac{\vert V(G)\vert}{2}\cdot\Delta(G)$$